# Would a question about improving the performance of a third-party database be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Microsoft's Windows Server Update Services product (WSUS) makes use of a database, which unfortunately performs very poorly.  There is a third-party script available that modifies the database (I believe simply by adding additional indexes) and my experience is that it improves the performance of WSUS by orders of magnitude, but it is no longer available free of charge.

My guess is that any professional DBA could easily improve the performance of the WSUS database, but I'm not sure this is an appropriate place to look for this kind of assistance.

**Would asking a question about how to improve the performance of the WSUS database be on-topic on Database Administrators?**

(For reference, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/984827/wsus-mmc-keep-crashing#comment1281803_984827) is the original Server Fault question I'm trying to help with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be helpful we would need the table definition(s), query and query plan. Are you sure your license terms allow you to share these details with internet randoms?

Asking if your license allows you to share product details with internet randoms is *definitely* off topic.

Comment: I figure most Windows DBAs already have access to a WSUS server, so I was vaguely hoping to find someone who had already solved the performance problem at their own site.  That may of course be overly optimistic.

Comment: OK, I think I'll take that as a "no".  Thanks.